# At remix.ethereum.org, blockhash function always zeroes all variables

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix, tron

I'm having a problem with the **blockhash** function at remix.ethereum.org.
Despite several attempts with different codes the blockhash function always causes problems and the result is that all variables are returned with a value of zero.

In the case below, the **_previousBlockNumber** variable always return zeroed.
If the blockhash function line is commented out then the error does not occur and at least the **_previousBlockNumber** variable returns correctly.

I've tried several different versions of compilers.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;
contract Test {
    constructor() public {
    }
    function rand() public view returns(uint,bytes32) {
        uint _previousBlockNumber;
        bytes32 _previousBlockHash;
        _previousBlockNumber = uint(block.number - 1);
        bytes32 _previousBlockHash = bytes32(blockhash(_previousBlockNumber)); 
        return (_previousBlockNumber,_previousBlockHash);
    }   
}
```

It's a bug issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, try to make your function not "view", you can see that if the assignment is performed the transaction does revert. So since you are performing a "local" read you receive 0. Perhaps, it is an issue with the Javascript VM. Did you try to run a local network and attach remix to a running instance, I think that in this case it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run this code to fix the problem and it's working for me with some changes. Same contract you can find on Rinkebey Testnet with this address `0x86ee6d633fd691e77dc79cbdb2a9fb108f79ecbd`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;
contract Test {
    uint256 i;
    constructor() public {
    }
    function rand() public view returns(uint,bytes32) {
        uint _previousBlockNumber;
        bytes32 _previousBlockHash;
        _previousBlockNumber = uint(block.number - 1);
        _previousBlockHash = bytes32(blockhash(_previousBlockNumber)); 
        return (_previousBlockNumber,_previousBlockHash);
    }  

    function setI(uint256 k) public{
        i = k;
    }
}
```

Initially, you were declaring the `_previousBlockHash` two times, and second time on the line of `blockhash` function. I fix it and working fine.

Secondly, in the current contract code you are not changing any state of the contract and not doing any transaction, `rand()` is just an call, which will not add any other block. So it will always remain `0`. I add one dummy transaction function for testing which is working fine now.

Lastly, try to run this on live test network to see actual things.
Hope it will work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the help. But the result is still zero for me. 
I made a screen copy of this link https://imgur.com/apzHISt

Comment: try to use some actual test net, like rinkebey or ropsten, you need metamask installed in the browser, and in remix use injected web3 instead of Javascript VM. In my understanding in the local machine it is zero block. try in actual test network.

Comment: I have edit my answer with more explanation, please check @leorzz

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I understand how to get around this problem.